# Prevent window from scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have full width slider as main background of website and use jquery to show or hide div depending on clicked link. Since some sections are longer then initial view my page scroll to bottom after click. How can i prevent window from scrolling to bottom ?

I use Bootstrap and jquery vegas slider plugin for full width slider.

JS

```
$(function() {
    $("nav li a").click(function() {
        $(".wrapper").addClass("hide")
        var page = $(this).attr("href")
        $(page).fadeIn("slow").toggleClass("hide")

        })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `event.preventDefault()` to [prevent browser](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) action.

According to [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

> Description:
>
> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be
>   triggered.

```
$(function() {
    $("nav li a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        $(".wrapper").addClass("hide")
        var page = $(this).attr("href")
        $(page).fadeIn("slow").toggleClass("hide")

        })
});
```

Comment: @Ganga Does it fix your problem?

Comment: Yes i just checked it :) Thank you , that was very fast.